# Inheritance Access Issue

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor, default-constructor

Am geting the following error, "Use of deleted function 'Derived::Derived'" while executing the below code related to Inheritance. Also in the note it says, "Derived::Derived() is implicitly deleted because
the default definition would be ill informed". Can someone help me in fixing this:

```
#include <iostream>

//BASE CLASS
class Base
{
public:
    int a;
    
    void display()
    {
        std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << std::endl;
    }
    
    //constructor
    Base(int la, int lb, int lc) : a {la}, b {lb}, c {lc}
    {
        
    }

protected:
    int b;

private:
    int c;
};

//DERIVED CLASS
class Derived : public Base
{
    //a from Base is Public
    //b from Base is Protected
    //c from Base has No access
    
public:
    void access_base_members()
    {
        a = 100;    //OK since a is Public in parent
        b = 200;    //OK since b is Protected type in Parent. So derived CLASS will have access
        //c = 300;    //NOK since c is private in parent and hence cannot be accessed
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << "\nBase Member access=>\n\n";
    
    Base base(1,2,3);
    base.a = 10; //OK
    //base.b = 20; //NOK since Protected
    //base.c = 30; //NOK since Private
    base.display();

    Derived derived;
    derived.a = 111;        //OK since public in parent
    //derived.b = 222;        //NOK since protected members cannot have direct access in OBJECTS
    //derived.c = 333;        //NOK since private
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The base class does not have the implicit default constructor because there is explicitly declared constructor

```
Base(int la, int lb, int lc) : a {la}, b {lb}, c {lc}
{
    
}
```

So the default constructor of the derived class that by default has to call the default constructor of the base class is defined as deleted.

Thus the compiler issues an error message for this declaration

```
Derived derived;
```

You need explicitly to define a constructor for the derived class.

For example you could define it like

```
Derived() : Base( 0, 0, 0 )
{
}
```

Or/and

```
Derived(int la, int lb, int lc ) : Base( la, lb, lc )
{
}
```